# Squiggly Line Above Note

Tags: piano, notation, j-s-bach, ornaments

I just found a Bach score (Invention #1, BWV 772), and there is this squiggly line above the `B` eighth note in the first measure (and a few other places). [This](http://imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/1/11/IMSLP00747-BWV0772.pdf) is the score.  What does it mean?

[image: Bach Invention #1, m. 1]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a trill, not a mordent. It actually starts on the upper auxiliary. The table below is from the *Clavier-Büchlein vor Wilhelm Friedemann Bach*, i.e., it is Bach's own. You can read more about it [here](http://www.pennuto.com/music/jsb_ornm.htm).

This a duplicate of [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30808/bach-how-is-this-mordent-to-be-realized-why-do-people-play-it-like-a-trill/30812#30812).

[image]

Comment: It only has meaning in how it is played, Jacob. It's called a trill and it's played as one.

Comment: it actually does look like a mordent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordent) and not a trill (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trill_(music)).

Comment: My pleasure. The thing to remember about the Baroque is that ornaments using the upper auxiliary (when they weren't sliding up to it from beneath the principal note) tended to act like appoggiature: they almost always started on the dissonance.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me on that. I deleted my incorrect answer that said it was a mordant. It's confusing how Bach used symbols differently than we do now!

Comment: @NickB., blame the Romantics for that one. It was pretty much in their time that trills and trill variants that commence on the main note rather than the auxiliary became the norm. ;)